# What happens now the UK has left the EU?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Given that leave is confirmed to have won the EU referendum, what happens now?

Will David Cameron resign? If so does that mean we will have a new PM negotiating the UK's exit deal?

And how long is the process of exiting the EU likely to take?

Comment: It will take 2 years max, it is written in the article 50 of the European Constitution.
Everything else can't be answered, it depends of what UK people do.

Comment: @GautierC - You mean 2 years minimum.

Comment: @KentaroTomono - Excuse me, but 48% of us voted to stay in (well... there was only a 72% turn out, so just over a third voted out, a third voted in, and a third didn't bother to turn up). And yes, I agree with you on the Scottish independence thing. I am frankly planning a move north of the border.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins nop, maximum. The UK is still bound to the EU for maximum 2 years if they can't find any agreement.

Comment: @GautierC, I was wrong. I was under a misapprehension on that part. I suppose it does make it less likely that Scotland will leave the UK before the UK leaves the EU now.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Actually I don't think. If Scotland want to be in the EU, it may be possible a fast independance treaty will be signed with the pressure of the EU, same goes for the Northern Ireland which want to be attached to the Eire.

Comment: Westminster will fight against another referendum in Scotland, despite the overwhelming support for the EU up there being seen by Edinburgh as a clear mandate for one. The UK won't last. London will probably end up leaving in a decade or two.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I am sorry for you, but in France, we hate *traitors*, so it is possible that all commercial relation will be cut with UK if they leave. And Scotland will have our full support, which will end up with either a commercial pressure, either a political one to let them decide their fate :/ Especially since we got our national election next years, government will do as people want to be reelected.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins don't hesitate to update me on the situation in UK, I am really interested in it.

Comment: Do please realise that the UK has NOT left the European Union. All that has happened is that on one day last week 52% of the 72% of the electorate who turned up to vote, indicated a wish to leave. Britain will not have left the European Union until two years following the invocation of Article 50 by a British goverment, IF THAT EVER HAPPENS.

Comment: Those who voted for Leave are now regretting to have voted so, I must say, Democracy is an **Idiocracy**! Think before you vote.

Comment: Important point: The UK hasn't actually left the EU, the referendum (just about) voted to leave, whether/when we leave is a different matter.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I believe the common consensus is it is max 2 years if we follow the EU rules. Theoretically we could change our law to leave sooner, but realistically Parliament wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nobody knows. Much of what is going to / might / will happen is purely speculative, as none of it has happened before (Greenland left, but that was as an autonomous region of Denmark, not the third largest economy in the EU).

However, David Cameron has announced he will step down as Prime Minister in October.
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-36615028

In the [European rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_from_the_European_Union), UK has 2 years to leave the EU, but he would be able to leave earlier if an agreement is found.

Concerning the intention of leaving from the UK, it may be giving during the discussions [around the UK referendum](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/meetings/european-council/2016/06/28-29/) in the European Council the 28th and 29th of June.

But apparently Mr Cameron doesn't want to be [the leader of the Brexit](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-eu-cameron-idUSKCN0ZA11H).

> I think it's right that this new prime minister takes the decision about when to trigger article 50 and start the formal and legal process of leaving the EU

**Update: 26th June**
The BBC released this chart outlining the process for the UK leaving.
[image: Src. http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-36632579]

Comment: Note that the 2 years is measured from when the UK announces to the European Council that it wishes to withdraw, and there isn't yet a timetable for that.

Comment: @origimbo true, but it *should* be the 28th or 29th of June, during the European Council.

Comment: @Gautier C Do you have a reference for that? Nothing I could find made it obvious that anyone actually in power had given any firm commitment on that front, and gave estimates ranging from two weeks to months,

Comment: @origimbo The [agenda](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/meetings/european-council/2016/06/28-29/) of the European Council the 28th includes the UK referendum.

Comment: @origimbo I have edited the answer to add this information.

Comment: @GautierC It appears David Cameron's resignation speech included something along the lines of "I think it's right that this new Prime Minister takes the decision about when to trigger article 50 and start the process of leaving the EU." so that definitely makes it a timescale of months.

Comment: @origimbo Interesting, would you mind giving me a link ? We should update the answer to include that.

Comment: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-eu-cameron-idUSKCN0ZA11H

Comment: Of note, possibly nothing could happen.  The referendum isn't legally binding, and now Parliament has to take the steps to leave withdraw leaving the EU (including invoking Article 50 of the EU charter and the 1972 European Communities Act, reportedly).  Parliament could ultimately decide to not do anything (and risk the voters wrath), or a new election could be held electing new members of Parliament running on the promise to not leave the EU.  In short, we don't know anything yet. http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-32810887

Comment: @JimmyM. that is true, but I think it will anyway give a mark in the EU.

Comment: Actually, Algeria left the EU in 1962 when they left France, so Greenland was 2nd to leave and UK will be the 3rd.